# Forgot pattern for my old tablet; no recovery mode available, ADB key not verified (new computer)

Tags: recovery-mode, usb-debugging, locked-out

I have a 2013 Nexus 7. This nexus 7 is rooted and has an unlocked bootloader but however has no recovery option. (When the device was rooted for some reason it removed the recovery and now has no recover option. Device simply says no recovery).

Now I had to store it when I moved living locations and forgot about it. When I opened the container after about 2 years and found the tablet I then attempted to open it. However when I stored it I realized I HAD SET A LOCK SCREEN PIN NUMBER ON IT! I have purchased a new computer since then so the computer doesnt have the USB debugging key on it for ADB to work on the tablet and I cant unlock the tablet to accept my new computer because I forgot the lock on it!

I am even willing to do a factory reset but I cant even do that because there is no recovery on this tablet. Is there ANYTHING I can do to get this lock screen off?? Hacking the software, programs, factory resets, hard resets, ANYTHING will work.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Since the bootloader is unlocked you have a variety of options to pick from and they don't require ADB.

#### Flash the recovery image to do factory reset

You can use [fastboot](/questions/tagged/fastboot) to flash a compatible recovery image. You can either pick the stock recovery image from [official source](https://developers.google.com/android/images#razor) or choose a custom recovery like [TWRP](https://twrp.me/devices/asusnexus72013wifi.html).

When you're in fastboot mode, issue these commands in your console:

```
fastboot flash recovery FILE    
fastboot reboot
```

Replace FILE with the location where your downloaded recovery image exists.

Now you can boot into the recovery mode and do the factory reset.

#### When recovery image still doesn't work

If recovery image still doesn't work for you, issue these commands in fastboot mode to factory reset the device.

```
fastboot format data
fastboot format cache
fastboot reboot
```

Comment: It is perfectly possible to bypass the lockscreen with any credentials but I lack the time to re-test this.